# Popup Window with One windowhandler selenium, Chrome, C#

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium, popupwindow

I'm writing selenium test by using C#, Selenium.WebDriver3.3.0, and Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver2.32.0. I cannot enter a string in textbox of popup window. After I opened popup window, I only get one count of window handlers (driver.WindowHandles). 
I tried to use code below, but `finder.Click()` throws the exception:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverTimeoutException' occurred in
>   WebDriver.Support.dll Additional information: Timed out after 5
>   seconds.

I think because I only get one window handler after opening popup window. Can anyone help on this?

```
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='Name']"));
PopupWindowFinder finder = new PopupWindowFinder(driver);
// open popup window and get popup window handler
string popupWindowHandle = finder.Click(element);
```

[image: UI Image]

Comment: In general, Selenium should not make such mistake to get wrong window handles count. Can you make sure it's really a window, maybe a simulator one just looks like a window? And you wait enough time for pop-up window come out?

Comment: Our developer told me that this is Kendo popup window. What should I do?

Comment: My view:
<div>
<label class="ng-binding col-md-3 control-label" ng-class="{'col-md-3':true, 'control-label': searchFields[3].label,'mandatory':searchFields[3].criteriaMandatory }" style="text-align: right;padding:0;">   Full Name </label>
<div class="col-md-8">
<input id="Name" class="full-width form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-scope" ng-switch-default="" ng-model="searchFields[3].searchValue" style="height: 26px;" type="text"/>
</div>

Comment: It's not a real window(Generall, window has title bar, close/min/max button or it has itself html/body tag in its page source code),  so this why you only get one window handle. you no need to switch window in your code.

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshot I can see you are not opening a new Window. But a div that is laying on top of the content in your initial Window. 
This is why there is still one WindowHandle.

Do not use the PopupWindowFinder for this, but search in the existing window to the id of the input field.

Just use the following FindElement and you can find the input field:

```cs
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='Name']"));
```

Comment: When I use PopupWindowFinder.Click(), popup window opened, and got timeout exception. I tried to increasing waiting time to 10 sec, I still got timeout exception message.